# Snipcart plugin don't recognize the webhook URL

Tags: install

I've cloned the GitHub repository but the plugin won't recognize the webhook URL and the order is not placed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at this article: https://snipcart.com/blog/develop-a-snipcart-powered-website-locally-using-ngrok can be very useful while developing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your passing "localhost" as your URL, so when the snipcart server tries to get the URL you supplied it's actually tying to fetch it on its own host.

From my experience with these kinda things you need to supply a publicity accessible URL, so if you can find your public ip then maybe try that instead of localhost or upload to a staging server and then test it with a real domain.